# how to implement a exec command in tcl?

Tags: tcl

It is possible to call other programs from Tcl using the Tcl exec function. Let’s use this
command to create a Tcl script that will take all of the Tcl code you have written so far and
create a single PDF from it. The filename of the single PDF file should be TCL CODE.pdf.
Recall that the Tcl foreach command makes it very easy to go through a list of items.
You should use the exec command to call the Linux program called enscript to produce
a postscript file for each of the Tcl files. You should then use the Linux program called
ps2pdf to turn each of the postscript files into a PDF. Finally, merge all of the PDFs using
the Linux program called gs (short for ghostscript). Invoke ghostscript using the following
command

Comment: Homework on using the builtin `exec` command?

Comment: Also, in English “how to implement” is a question about how to create a thing, not how to use that thing. You are not interested in the exact code to make pipeline construction work across platforms, but rather how to call the `exec` command that already exists.

Answer (score -1):

Some documentation

- [Tcl documentation](http://www.tcl-lang.org/doc/)
- [the exec man page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm)
- [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)
- [the wiki entry for exec](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec)